# Distribution of primes and product of primes

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

I know for large numbers $\le N$, the distribution of primes is about $N / \ln(N)$. I want to know thet distribution for primes and the product of unique primes ($p_0, ..., p_0 p_1, ..., p_0 p_1 p_2,...)  \le N $. In that case, the only numbers left over are numbers with a prime factor to a power greater than 1. I am guessing $eN/\ln(n)$ based on the sum of factorials but I really have no idea.

Comment: @WillJagy Ok, then it follows to find the cubefree, 4th-powerfree, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to count square-free numbers. Let $S(x)$ be the number of square-free numbers in $[1,x]$. Then:

$$S(x)=\frac{6x}{\pi^2}+O(\sqrt{n}). $$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution.